# compare each row in first column with all rows in second column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with two columns. I want to compare each row of the first column with all rows in the second column. If matched I need to insert yes in the 3rd column, if not I need to insert no.

```
First second
A      B
C      D
E      A
X      c
```

Output should be

```
First second  yesOrno
A      B         yes
C      D         yes
E      A         NO
X      c         NO
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49631010/edit) and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Also please see **[ask]**.

Comment: You have several random guesses at answers so far. They all look reasonable but are all three very different from each other. This is because your question doesn't make much sense. "Each row of the first column"??? What does that mean?

Comment: What chapter of the book is this homework for?   You should probably solve this with whichever technique the teacher is covering right now so he doesn't know you cheated and posted on SO.

Comment: Can you add more information?

Answer (score 2):

Use an `EXISTS` with the same table.

```
UPDATE T1 SET
    ThirdColumn = CASE WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT
            'a SecondColumn match exists'
        FROM
            YourTable AS T2
        WHERE 
            T1.FirstColumn = T2.SecondColumn) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
FROM
    YourTable AS T1
```

Comment: I didn't get your query. I want to compare the first row in the first column with the second column. If it exists I want to insert yes in third column else no. And again the second row in the first column with all rows in the second column

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
     First, Second,
     CASE WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM Table t2 
        WHERE t2.Second = t1.First) 
        THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS YesOrNo
FROM
     Table t1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get it by self join as below

```
  select T1.First,T1.second,(case when T2.second is null then 'no' else 'yes' end) as yesOrno from T as T1 left join T as T2
    on T1.First=t2.second
```

check sql fiddle : [SQL Fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0632183ad361c4dcda94df3e6b2fba49)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
declare @t table (
    C1 char(1),
    C2 char(1)
)

insert  @t
values  ('A','B'),
        ('C','D'),
        ('E','A'),
        ('X','C')

select  t1.C1,t1.C2, case when t2.C2 is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end YesOrNo
from    @t t1 left join @t t2
        on t1.C1 = t2.C2
```

There are many different ways of writing this basic query.

Comment: Was about to post similar, however you will want a group by  on t1.c1 and MAX/pivot the case statement if you only want 1 row per result